# What plausible circumstances would cause the stranded people to not be found?

Tags: spaceships

So, a crew of about 500 men and women, who were on a vessel transporting seeds and earth animals, like horses, dogs, and etc. were nearly at their destination, when they were struck by an abandoned EMP emitter from a past battle. They were above a planet that was just evolving single celled microbial life, and they all crash landed. The planet had lakes and oceans, and an atmosphere breathable by humans. But there is a problem.

Most spacecrafts produced by that company, Galaxy Intrepid, are built with items that can help a stranded ship be found. A location emitter gives a ships location up until it is found, and dispatch a detail of rescuer drones to try and rescue survivors. This Emitter cannot be broken easily, as it is made of Talutonium, a near indestructible material, and the drones search every inch of a planet until the survivors are found. And, the crew of any ship have uniforms that single them out to the drones. So, what plausible circumstances could cause these people to remain stranded?

Comment: Close voters: Please add comments when voting to close. The asker can't improve the question if you don't provide feedback

Comment: Ohh man, I’m so sorry about that. I promise that won’t happen again. Sorry, all the users on this website are good people, and that was a totally unprovoked lash of anger

Comment: @Pingcode The asker has asked 36 questions since joining this SE. They should already know what is expected at this point. 30 of those 36 questions have 5 or less votes, which, in an up-vote trigger-happy user base, is extremely low. Furthermore, 21 (nearly 2 thirds) of those questions are on hold or closed. It shows that the user continually ignores advice from comments, neglects to fix their questions, and instead opts to continue to post poor content. If they're not going to listen, why should we provide feedback?

Comment: @DTCooper To add to what Aify said: Posting too many poorly-received questions in a short space of time can result in you being temporarily suspended from posting questions. There are users here who can testify to that. I have no idea how close you are to that threshold, but in future, you need to start thinking more carefully about the questions you post here.

Comment: The easiest reason is: someone up there doesn't want them to be found.

Comment: @Aify: That many, how is that even possible. I have 758 upvotes in total

Comment: If you're talking about votes cast, that's the amount of votes that you've cast personally on other people's questions. I'm talking about the votes other people have put on your questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, let me get this straight.

- You've got a spaceship with a crew of 500 people trying to colonize a planet inhabited by nothing more complex than bacteria.
- An EMP takes out their ship's electrical systems shortly before arrival.
- Because of that, the ship crashes into the planet.
- At least some of the crew survives.
- The ship had an emergency transmitter made of a near-indestructable material intended to send a distress signal to other ships, including automated rescue drones.
- If they come to the planet, the drones will search every inch of the planet's surface.
- The crew members have uniforms intended to make them extra visible to the drones.
- None of the surviving crew members are found and rescued.

Ways this could happen:

- The rescue drones never make it to the planet

  - The emergency transmitter fails to summon them

    - The emergency transmitter was taken out by the EMP, because its indestructium casing doesn't act as a Faraday cage. A solid metal casing normally would, but then it wouldn't be able to transmit anything, so maybe it has an antenna sticking out
    - The distress signal is blocked by some quirk of the planet's atmosphere (a really strong ionosphere?) or something elsewhere in the solar system
    - The humans sabotaged the transmitter because they don't want to be found
  - The emergency transmitter summons them to the wrong planet

    - The ship missed the planet entirely, so the crew bailed out using escape pods, while the ship itself went floating off into space
    - The ship blew up in the atmosphere, and the transmitter got ejected into interplanetary space
    - The humans threw the transmitter out an airlock in interplanetary space because they don't want to be found
- The rescue drones reach the planet, but fail to find the survivors

  - The drones only search for uniforms, and will ignore any non-uniformed survivors

    - The uniforms were left behind on the ship and destroyed when it crashed
    - By the time the drones arrived, the uniforms were dirtied and/or damaged to the point that the drones could no longer recognize them
    - By the time the drones arrived, the uniforms had worn out completely and the survivors had begun wearing clothes made from locally-grown materials
    - The survivors ditched their uniforms because they do not want to be found
  - The survivors make camp in an area where the drones cannot find them, uniforms or not

    - In a cave, because free shelter
    - Under the ocean, because high levels of ionizing radiation from the Sun or something
  - The survivors deliberately hide themselves from the drones, because they do not want to be found

Comment: They are not trying to colonize the planet. They are transporting cargo. Maybe read my question before making fun of it SMH

Comment: @DTCooper I wasn't trying to make fun of your question; I was trying to make sure I understood it- which, apparently, I did not. You made no mention of any other humans living on the planet, so I assumed there were none. You might want to edit the question to make that clear. And in any case, most if not all of my proposed solutions should still work if there are already colonists.

Comment: Oh sorry, forgive me for the misunderstanding, it’s just an accident

Comment: I'd like to add the ship might of crashed into a cave system so the drones could find the ship, but the debris is now blocking the entrance, hence your survivors are trapped inside the cave system and can't be found due to how extensive the cave network is

Answer (score 1):

You answered your own question

"when they were struck by an abandoned EMP emitter from a past battle"

It might have been an EMP mine and they can't get to the survivors. They might know where they are but trying to clear a minefield is slow and dangerous work.

Between EMP mines and automated defense drones, nobody can get to the planet to rescue them.

Comment: Oh, my, I am so sorry. I forgot to mention in the question that the emitter was EMP proof. It is kept behind a magnetic shield

Comment: Doesn't matter. EMP mines destroy ships. Rescuers don't want to crawl through a minefield. The rescuers know exactly where they are. They just can't get to them.

Answer (score 0):

### Bury It

No mention of FTL, subspace or hyperspace comms were mentioned so I'm going to assume normal EM radio comms.

The transmitter is buried so that even when broadcasting at max power, it came overcome the shielding effects of the local rock or dirt. Perhaps the ship embedded itself in some deposit of high quality iron ore or some other radio insulating ore when it crashed.

Compounding this problem, the ship could have crashed on a planet with an unusually active magnetosphere that significantly attenuates radio signals on the wavelengths the transmitter uses. It's also common (and I've seen it happen in person) where a radio channel will just go dead and not permit transmission at all.

If the drones can't find the transmitter, they can't search the planet for survivors.

Answer (score 0):

**The ship did not come down with them.**

The ship was not in orbit when hit by the EMP.  It was some distance out,  and was disabled but not catastrophically.  The crew and some cargo got into escape pods and abandoned ship, launching themselves at the nearby planet after determining it was a reasonable one for them.

The disabled ship continued on its path, perhaps slingshotting around the planet into a different trajectory.  Maybe it wound up in the star of that system - too much for even Talutonium.  Or it crashed much later into a different planet, wasting the time of the drones sent there.